# Pass parameters when compiling a dll in c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

It is possible to send parameters when compiling a project in VS?

I have a .dll and it has to be compiled for more countries. The country id it is needed the code, that's why I need separated builds for every country. So, I was thinking if there is a way to send the country id as a parameter at compilation, no to modify the code every time I need to do a build for a certain country?

Comment: Have you considered loading country params from config file?

Comment: Pre-defined preprocessor macros?

Comment: preprocessor symbols, and multiple configurations?

Comment: I am new to these things...But multiple configurations sounds like an option. I will try out. Thanks

Comment: You can add an Initialize method and pass the country code to this method.

Comment: Since it's Windows, a registry setting is also a conventional and convenient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will briefly tackle some descriptions of the pros and cons of each approach mentioned above, although I would tend to use the locale file approach unless there were a very strong case, or requirement, for obfuscation via separate compiled dlls.

- load the content that varies by country/language via a locale resource file; the code will remain the same but strings, formulae etc can all be loaded from a resource on the filesystem which has the relevant entries for the locale chosen.

  - **Advantages**: single codebase; multiple locale files; easy code maintenance; single release targets all locales that a resource exists for; can be easily expanded to new regions by addition of a simple resource/locale file
  - **Disadvantages**: requires external resource/locale file
- use `#define` to wrap code so that each compilation route depends on a particular `#define`:

  - **Advantages**: releases are more secure, as all material is within a compiled dll;
  - **Disadvantages**: compilation is more complex as it requires parameterisation; addition of new locales means addition of code to the codebase; scope for errors to be introduced is multiplied by the number of locales to be supported + 1
- **Multiple configurations**: this has the same issues and advantages as using `#define`s